# How to implement Round Robin Scheduling in C# using list view

Tags: c#, round-robin

I'm stuck and confused on where I should save the unfinished process and manipulate it again together with the processes that arrived on the latest time frame. My queue resets every time it checks whether new process is available.

```
//pcount is the no. of process
//tq is the time quantum
string[] process = new string[pcount];
        string[] bt_container = new string[pcount];
        string[] ct = new string[pcount];
        string[] tat = new string[pcount];
        string[] wt = new string[pcount];
        int c = 0;
        int at_counter = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int timer = 0;
        int tq = (int)tq_value.Value;
        Array.Copy(bt, bt_container, pcount);
        for (int i = 0; i < pcount; i++)
        {
            process[i] = (i + 1).ToString();
        }
        g = timer = 0;
       // at_dummy[0] = "10000";
        while (pcount > 0)
        {
            c = 0;
            at_counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(pnum.Text); i++)
            {
                if (timer >= int.Parse(at_dummy[i]))
                {
                    at_counter++;
                }
            }
            int[] bt_temp = new int[at_counter];
            for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(pnum.Text); i++)
            {
                if (timer >= int.Parse(at_dummy[i]))
                {
                    bt_temp[c] = int.Parse(bt_container[i]);
                    c++;
                }
            }
            Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
            for (int p=0;p<bt_temp.Length;p++)
            {
                if (bt_temp[p] != 0)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(bt_temp[p]);
                }
            }
            if ((queue.ElementAt(0) - tq) != 0)
            {
                if (at_counter > 1)
                {
                    int temp = queue.ElementAt(0);
                    queue.Dequeue();
                    queue.Enqueue(temp);
                }
            }
            bt_container[Array.IndexOf(bt_container, (queue.ElementAt(0).ToString()))] = (queue.ElementAt(0) - tq).ToString();
            if (bt_container[Array.IndexOf(bt_container, (queue.ElementAt(0).ToString()))].Equals("0"))
            {
                at_dummy[Array.IndexOf(bt_container, (queue.ElementAt(0).ToString()))] = "10000";
            }
                timer += tq;
        }
```